# problema con header de X-Auth-Token en script python

Tags: python, api, tokens

Estoy haciendo un script que autentique con la api de openstack y me coga datos, el problema llega a la hora de autenticar, tengo un X-Auth token, que introduzco con argumentos:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description= info, formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-t', '--token', help='openstack api token', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

user_token = args.token
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization':'X-Auth-Token ' +  user_token
}
```

```
req = {
    "flavors": "http://myip/v2.1/flavors",
    "images": "http://myip/v2.1/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images "
}
# get account data
try:
    result = requests.get(req["images"], headers=headers)
    result_data = json.loads(result.content)
except Exception as e :
    print('0')
    sys.exit("\nError requesting %s, please check conectivity" %(req["images"],))

if 'errors' in result_data :
    print('0')
    sys.exit(F'Error token, please check token: {result_data}')
```

el problema es que no llega a autenticar con la api, puede ser que meta mal el token en el header¿

Comment: No se supone que en el `Authorization` debe ir solo el token?

Comment: Lo he puesto asi y me sale  Error requesting http://ip/images , please check conectivity, antes devolvía esto: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openstack.py", line 243, in <module>
    desc = "Openstack image is  %s " %str(result_data['error']['minDisk'] ),
KeyError: 'minDisk' , por lo que llegaba a conectarse